# Is this process OK to replace URL structure?

Tags: categories, urls

I need to update the URL format from `site.com/parent1/article` to `site.com/category1/article`.

I see the process as follows:

1. Replace parent pages with category pages
2. Assign the right category to each article (parent1 > category1, parent2 > category2,...)
3. Change permalinks settings so that URLs use category instead of parent
4. Setup redirects to serve 301 from parent1 to category1,...
5. (If necessary remove parent setting as not needed anymore)

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Posts aren't hierarchical by default, so are the "articles" Pages right now? If so, you'll also need to convert their post types. You can either change that in the database, or re-create each Page as a Post when you also assign the right Category to the Post.

Comment: Good point. Articles are pages and a plugin is used to add categories to pages. Don't ask me why...